# SQL query fails in arcpy, but works in ArcGIS Pro 'select by attributes'

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, where-clause

I'm building an SQL query in Python that is used to make a feature layer, but the feature layer returns no features, when it should return 1169 features.  The query below works on 95% of the data (1955-2017), but fails to find the 2018-2019 data.  When I copy the exact string printed in the python console into the SQL 'select by attributes' window in ArcGIS Pro, it works as expected (see screenshot).  Code sample is:

```
for year in years:
    for event in types:
        where_clause = f"Year = '{year}' and Type = '{event}'"
        print(where_clause)
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(spc, "temp_lyr", where_clause)
        print(f"Number of {event} events in {year}: {arcpy.management.GetCount('temp_lyr')}")
```

for example, returns:

```
Year = '2018' and Type = 'Tornado'
Number of Tornado events in 2018: 0
```

[image]

The original data (1955-2017) was imported into a feature class from a shapefile. The 2018-2019 data was added with an insert cursor from a CSV that had lat/lon information and the same fields.  That seems to be the only difference in rows that work and don't work in arcpy.  They are text fields and I've already cleaned up all whitespace.  Any ideas what could be going wrong?

The data is in a file geodatabase.  I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.2 with Python 3.6.6.

p.s. I also already tried wrapping the query in a docstring and adding double quotes around the field name.

```
where_clause = f""""Year" = '{year}' and "Type" = '{event}'"""
```

which returns something like:

```
"Year" = '2018' and "Type" = 'Tornado'
```

Here's a sample of the table.  In my arcpy script the first two rows (2017, Tornado) will be included in the layer in the correct iteration of the loop.  The next two rows (2018, Tornado) will not be included.  All fields are text except for Lon/Lat.

[image]

Comment: I get a syntax error on where_clause = f"Year = '{year}' and Type = '{event}'", what is it in python without the syntax error? Is the leading f for a reason? Is it supposed to be r with a format statement at the end? I don't have the data to check but is year a string, date or integer field? You shouldn't need the quotes around the field names, it's never been a problem in desktop so Pro should be no different.

Comment: I see, in python 3 the leading *f* is an improved formatting, I read about it https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/ and now it makes a bit more sense. Considering your quotation in the select by attributes dialog the date field must be a string or behaving like a string at least. I'm not certain you can use GetCount in the manner that you are using it, GetCount returns a *result object* not a number, read https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm and look at the example 2, at the very least it should be {arcpy.management.GetCount('temp_lyr')[0]}.

Comment: What is one row of data that your expression fails on?  With that it should be easy to test.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I see your point on the referencing item [0] from the GetCount result object.  However, the code returns a valid count for 95% of the loop iterations, and returns 0 for the other 5%.  I've since changed it to `arcpy.management.GetCount('temp_lyr')[0]`, and still get the same result.

Comment: Then the problem is possibly in your data or your variables, is there a leading or trailing space? Is your database case sensitive? (pGDB aren't but fGDB are). Not having the data (or Pro) to test I can't be any more helpful. Intermittent problems and those that don't work as expected like this are the hardest to diagnose. Double check years and types variables, perform a summary statistic on the table with a case field both of Year and Type to ensure that there isn't some problem whitespace then if that doesn't work perhaps it's time to contact Esri support.

Comment: You might also consider setting the name of the parameter in the function...where_clause = where_clause. It might seem silly, but I've had that work before. Also, you keep using the same temporary layer. Maybe try and delete the temporary layer after the get_count to clear it out, or give each temporary layer a new name. Finally, you are comparing the Select Layer by Attributes to the Make Feature Layer option. Why not use SelectLayerByAttribute function and then getcount?

Comment: I still don't know what was going on here.  I eventually got around the issue by recreating my dataset, making sure that all non-floats were cast as strings in my insertCursor.  Adding `where_clause = where_clause` didn't help.  Converting everything to lower case didn't help.  Summary statistics on the table in ArcPro didn't show anything odd.  I was deleting the temporary layer in each iteration, it just wasn't shown in my sample code.   ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I've occasionally had issues of not remembering which data sources like to have their fields identified which ways, so I've started to use the Arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters to make sure it's always right.  
---
`where_clause = f""""Year" = '{year}' and "Type" = '{event}'"""`
would become:
`where_clause = '{} = {} and {} = {}'.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(spc, "Year"),year,arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(spc, "Type"),event)`